# Shell: selecting an available program

Tags: shell-script

In bash/ksh/zsh, is there an good idiom to set a variable to the first of a list of alternative programs that can be found in `$PATH` (or otherwise callable by the shell)?

For instance, if I have a script that needs to work whether *realpath(1)* is installed under `realpath` or `grealpath`, I could go the long way around:

```
 if type "grealpath" > /dev/null; then
    realpath_exec=grealpath
  elif type "realpath" > /dev/null; then
    realpath_exec=realpath
  else
    echo "$0: No realpath found in PATH" >&2
    exit 1
  fi
```

Most of the ways I can think of building an expression with `||` and `&&` either need nested subshells (not a huge deal, just annoying and bad for performance in a frequently-called function) and/or complicated redirections or ugly `grep`'s to deal with the various outputs. (Note that the *output* of `type` or `which` is not directly usable if the installed "program" is a function or alias; therefore, if I just want to assume that if something available to me called `realpath` can do the job, I must switch on return value rather than output or do a grep.)

The above is fine, it's just really wordy and if you have multiple programs choices like this, it's painfully so. Is there a more *elegant* way I can pick the first available program of a list and assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward and comprehensible way would just be a `for` loop with a single one of your `if`s inside it, which `break`s out of the loop when it finds a match.

---

If you don't want to do that, in Bash, [`type` accepts multiple arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-type) to search for:

```
type grealpath realpath ...
```

and the first word of the output line for a matching entry is always<sup>1</sup> the name of the command/function/alias. You can capture the standard output in an array and index into it to avoid a further subprocess:

```
words=($(type realpath grealpath foo make 2>/dev/null))
realpath_exec=${words[0]}
if ! [ "$realpath_exec" ] ...
```

From a certain point of view, this is elegant, but it's decidedly harder to understand when you chance across it.

---

Word-splitting in array initialisers [depends on](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays) the value of [`IFS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-IFS). If `IFS` has been changed, or if any of your commands contain a space, this won't work.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Experimentally, this appears to be the case in *most* locales, even where that is not the natural word order, and there appears always to be a U+0020 ASCII space afterwards, but the output format isn't further specified. In some localisations, this won't work; you need to consider whether that's going to be a problem for you. You can use `LC_ALL=C type ...` to (more-or-less) guarantee a suitable output format.</sub>

---

**In zsh**, if you only care about executables, and not functions or aliases, you can use [`$commands`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-commands):

```
realpath_exec=${commands[grealpath]:-${commands[realpath]:-${commands[another]:?No compatible command found}}}
```

The `${param:-...}` expansion gives the value of `param` if it's non-null, and `...` otherwise; `${param:?...}` errors out with `...` if `param` fails.
This remains fairly ugly.

If you don't care about the ordering between selection of commands, you can use a simpler version with the [(i) subscript flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Subscript-Flags):

```
realpath_exec=${commands[(i)realpath|grealpath|another]}
```

To include functions and aliases as well in either of these, you could use `$functions` and `$aliases`, but it will get repetitive.

Comment: In zsh, unfortunately, `type` outputs everything to stdout, including "%s not found", so that isn't quite portable. The for loop works, though, and it does look better than the `if`/`elif`.I'm still wondering if there's an expression-based way though; I found one for zsh, but there's literally no way to suppress the stderr messages (since it uses a shell syntax trick rather than a subshell whose stderr you can redirect) without running it in an `eval`, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: @Trey - you don't need a subshell or `eval` to redirect stderr. `set -x; echo some stuff; : and show the xtrace; { set +x; : don\'t show this xtrace; } 2>/dev/null` - it works the same way a subshell does *(as a compound command)*. try it with `if stuff; then other stuff; fi 2>/dev/null`

Comment: mikeserv: true. I was thinking about the `=cmd` zsh syntax though, which expands to the full path of `cmd`; since it's part of the shell syntax rather than a command argument, redirection doesn't work unless you use the equals syntax inside a subshell or `eval`. I did say I wanted aliases and functions, though, and equals syntax doesn't give you that. But that's a judgment call, I'd use a solution that didn't work for aliases and functions if it were _much_ cleaner.  A `var=${=cmd1 || =cmd2 || =cmd3}` kind of thing, for instance, would be hands-down better, even if it only worked for execs.

Comment: @Trey There are both of `${commands[cmd1]:-${commands[cmd2]:-${commands[cmd3]:?No compatible command found}}}` and `${commands[(i)cmd1|cmd2|cmd3]}` available, and variations of same.

Answer (score 2):

You could refactor it, e.g., into:

```
isExecutable(){ type "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1 && printf "%s\n" "$1"; }

realpath_exe=`isExecutable grealpath || isExecutable realpath`  
[ -n "$realpath_exe" ] || {
   echo "$0: No realpath found in PATH" >&2
   exit 1
}
```

but I think you're version is fine and readable. I wouldn't worry about its length.

Please note that you can't have dollar signs on the left hand side of variable assignments and also that `type` also looks for functions and aliases in addition to executable files in PATH.

Comment: Oops on the dollar-signs, I was rewriting my actual code with less code-specific variable names and typed a dollar out of habit. Fixed.

Comment: `type` does return functions and aliases in ksh and zsh.

Comment: @Trey Typo. That's what I meant to say. The way you phrased your questions you made it looks as if you thought it only returned executable files from PATH.

Comment: Ah, sorry; can I rewrite "if I just want to assume that if something available to me called `realpath` can do the job" to make it clear that I _am_ happy accepting functions and aliases? It's the reason I used the term "programs" instead of "executables" as I would if I weren't including those other runnables.

Answer (score 2):

You're right about the output of `type` and `which` : so you shouldn't use them. You should use `command`.

```sh
pathx()
    for   cmd
    do    set "" "${PATH:?is NULL!}:"
          while  "${2:+set}" -- "${2%%:*}" "${2#*:}" 2>&3
          do      command -v -- "${1:-.}/$cmd"
    done; done    3>/dev/null
```

That only does `command -v $PATH_component/$cmd` and so it won't ever list aliases or builtins or any of the rest - it will recursively search every component of its `$PATH` environment variable for every one of its arguments and print to its stdout any it finds.

If you add an `&& break` after `command -v ...` it will abort its `$PATH` search the first time it successfully locates a `$PATH`'d executable named for one of its arguments.

It was Michael Homer's idea - and it's really the best one.

It works by nesting the `while` loop within the `for` loop. `for` each iteration of the `for` loop, the `while` loop iterates over every component in `$PATH`, testing the shortest `:` colon-separated string it can slice `${2%%:*}` with `command -v $slice/$cmd` and saving the longest string for the next iteration `${2#*:}`. It is only when the `$PATH` has been tested completely that the `while` loop tries to execute a `"${2:-NUL}"`   string and fails that it completes and the next `for` iteration begins.

```sh
cp /bin/cat /tmp
(PATH=$PATH:/tmp pathx cat dd dummy doesntexist read echo)
```

---

```
/usr/bin/cat
/tmp/cat
/usr/bin/dd
/usr/bin/echo
```

Apparently you do want `aliases` and stuff. Well, that's doable:

```
shellx()
    for  cmd
    do  "set"  --   "$cmd";"unset" cmd
         for   type  in     alias  exe
         do    case  $type  in
               (a*)        "alias"  "${1%%*=*}"     ;;
               (e*)  PATH= "command" -v -- "$1"     &&
                            type=function::builtin  ||
                           "command" -v -- "$1"     ;;
               esac  >&2&& "command" -V -- "$1" >&3 &&
                     cmd=$("command" -v -- "$1")    && return
    done;done  3>&2 2>/dev/null
```

That was harder than I remember, but that quits as soon as one of its arguments is found to be executable. It puts its type - one of *alias*, *function::builtin*, or *exe* in *`$type`*, and the command goes in *`$cmd`*. Aliases get the definition written into `$cmd` - which in `zsh`, `bash`, and `yash` looks like...

```
alias x='something or other'
```

...in `ksh93` it is just...

```
something or other
```

...and in `dash` it is...

```
x='something or other'
```

...but, again, all get the variable *`$type`* assigned.

If you pass it an argument that *is* a shell alias and has somehow been defined even though its name contains `=`, then, well, this won't find it. If you need that functionality, you'll need to grep the output of `alias` rather than testing its return.

If an executable is found the `command -V` output is written to standard error just before the function returns. It returns false if no executable is found.

Comment: He actually does want to include aliases, functions, and builtins, though.

Comment: @MichaelHomer - well, it's a good thing that's a whole lot easier. thanks.